# Most basic way to read file contents into a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, file

...and I mean the MOST basic way. I have a filename, and I want to get its contents in a string called contents in a javascript funcrion in an html page.  Nothing dynamic, no input fields, no onload,..  the file is called contents.txt. All I want is a javascript function to just do that: get the file contents into the string.
Is there not something less than 5 lines long that does this? Firefox only. No checks, I don't care for any compatibility right now...

thanks!

Ps background: i am building a parser of some sort in JavaScript and for now I just want to test the darn thing with test data...

Comment: you have no access to your files when using js from a web browser due to some obvious security reasons

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648871/how-can-i-parse-a-text-file-using-javascript

Comment: The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46129280/1541186 had it down to a couple lines using `fetch`.

Comment: nice, it's been a while but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple approach, place the script tag at the end of the body.  This will ensure the page is fully loaded before it executes.

```
<script>
function done()
{
    var fileContents = this.response;
}

var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", done, false);
xmlhttp.open("GET","/contents.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
</body>
```