# Rearrange Textfile from javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried this one on youtube.
[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIjs6.png)
[Then I got this one which is difficult to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWb5B.png)

What I really want is like I want to seach the text with keyword "rainbow" from any user that tweets and write it into textfile sequencely.
Example :

Bob tweets : I love rainbow.
Jack tweets : Rainbow is what I love.
Cold tweets : I like rainbow.

Thanks guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a text file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648871/how-can-i-parse-a-text-file-using-javascript)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.