# Read txt file and put into javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to know how i could read a txt file and have the contents of it be into array in javascript.

My txt file looks something like this.
[Skin1],[skin2],[skin3],etc...

I simply want the array contents to be acquired from the txt file instead of writing the array into the actual html file.

I am fairly new to javascript and do not understand how to do this.

P.s. my html and txt files will be on the same server. If that makes a difference.

I would really appreciate an example code, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your text file's syntax is not valid JSON. I'd suggest fixing whatever produces the text file to save valid JSON instead, and then you could use `JSON.parse` to turn its text into an array immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a text file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648871/how-can-i-parse-a-text-file-using-javascript)

Comment: @CertainPerformance there's nothing in the question that has anything to do with JSON.

Comment: @DanielBeck No, but if the text is changed so that it *is* JSON, it'll be far easier for OP to work with it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't agree ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @DanielBeck - oh okay then. What makes you say that using some home-rolled scheme to record keys and their values will not be far harder than working with JSON, which already has the tooling to undo the file at the read-end. No seriously, how could JSON not be easier?

Comment: Looks like all they'd need to do is split on commas; I'm not sure what's so challenging about that.  But mostly my point is that we should answer the question they're asking, instead of trying to turn it into a different question on their behalf.

Comment: I am looking for guidance, i really dont know how to read a file that is my main question. If someone could provide an example of how to use the json way i would appreciate it. Thank you for quick responses

Comment: are you reading the text file client side (in the browser) or server side (using node) ? or is the browser reading a text file on the server?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, this would be more efficiently achieved if the text file was encoded in JSON. However without knowing how the text file is being produced I can't recommend a method to generate it as JSON, so here's how you might parse your current file.

Assuming you're are reading the content of the text file in the frontend, you would asynchronously get the content of the text file using `XMLHttpRequest`. Once you've received the file content you would turn it into an array. In the specific case that you've provided where the text file is of the form `[Skin1],[skin2],[skin3]`, you would remove the first `[` and last `]`, and then split by the delineation `],[`.

```
function httpGet(url, callback) {
    // this function gets the contents of the URL. Once the
    // content is present it runs the callback function.
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false );
    xmlhttp.send();    
}

httpGet("url-of-your-file", function(textFile){
    // this calls the httpGet function with the URL of your text
    // file. It then runs a function that turns the file into an
    // array.
    var array = textFile.slice(1, -1).split("],[");
    console.log(array);
});
```