# How to make JS read the contents of a local text file

Tags: javascript, arrays, txt

I know using JS to read the contents of a .txt is possible.

For example, I have a text file `code.txt` which contains

```
Abc
Ghi
123466
bored
idk
```

And I have `index.js`. I would like to use the contents of code.txt to create an array into index.js.

So, in that example, I would like an array like this to appear in index.js.

```
const entcode = [
  "Abc",
  "Ghi",
  "123466",
  "bored",
  "idk",
];
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hey maybe this one helps :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648871/how-can-i-parse-a-text-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using node.js you can use the [File system api](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

```js
const fs = require("fs");
let contents = fs.readFileSync("code.txt").toString().split(/\r?\n/);
console.log(contents);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes!

1. Install [Deno](https://deno.land/) (a JavaScript/TypeScript runtime that works outside your browser)
2. Read the file and create the array like this:

`./index.js`:

```js
const text = (await Deno.readTextFile('./code.txt')).trim();
const entcode = text.split(/\r?\n/);
console.log(entcode);
```

3. Run it:

```
$ deno run index.js
⚠️  ️Deno requests read access to "./code.txt". Run again with --allow-read to bypass this prompt.
   Allow? [y/n (y = yes allow, n = no deny)]  y
[ "Abc", "Ghi", "123466", "bored", "idk" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery you can get the data by the below code.

```
jQuery.get('http://localhost/code.txt', (data) => {
    const res = data;
});
```